# Can't register facebook app because of secure canvas url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a Facebook app. But during the registration process I can't move forward. It asks to enter secure canvas url. I heared that HTTPS will be compulsory from October. But I can't move forward, because I have only HTTP.

Please help me to solve this issue. I have another web site that works perfectly using HTTP and a Facebook app.

Comment: Facebook has an option that lets you get it hosted by a few services. See the APPS section under Developers. Heroku's one of them if I do remember. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Answer (score 0):

New apps will require https, compulsorily... To test your app for development, enter a https URL for your app, but turn off secure browsing to test :-)

To test with multiple users, try getting a self signed certificate and run HTTPS.

On production, get a proper SSL certificate from a CA and deploy it.

Comment: Thanks Karthik, but now I have only http , so can I use http for the app just for testing ?

Comment: I'm saying add a dummy https URL, and turn off secure browsing to only test with your account. Later, follow the other steps.

Comment: @user1467983 test locally (localhost) with https and self signed as Karthik said, in production it is not possible. You shouldn't be doing first testing of apps in production stage anyway

Comment: Dear Karthik, Can I use the working app for my new web site. I mean can I edit and change the domains of old app to the new web site domain ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same kind of problem but i have solved the problem by placing the same url with the https. Here is the both url demo.

```
Canvas URL:

http:// Site url

Secure Canvas URL

https:// Site url
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no problem using your app outside the FB**

Recently FB updated the SSL for Secure canvas url..It is not mean that we need to buy SSL certification

just create an app with your http://

then for secure canvas url simply add https://

here the secure canvas url is for putting ur url inside the FACEBOOK is not possible .but you can access all from outside of the FB

Check this site which has no https:// only http://
But it works clearly outside the FB
http://shop.samthesamurai.com/